# Proving the equivalence of a finite set

Tags: elementary-number-theory, cardinals

Let A be a finite set. Prove that if A≈n and A≈m, then n=m.

The answer in the book uses a max function, so I was just wondering if there was a simpler way. If not, it would be appreciated if someone could explain it a little better. Thanks!

Comment: What is the strange character between ""≈" and n in "A≈n" supposed to be (and mean)?

Comment: You need to fix that, Henning's not the only one seeing a mangled character. "Prove that if $A \approx ??? n$ and $A \approx ??? m$, then $n = m$."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could prove the contrapositive statement.

Suppose $n \neq m$.  Then prove there is no bijection between $\{1, \dots, n\}$ and $\{1, \dots, m \}$.  If you know about the [pigeonhole principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle), then this part is easy, because you just invoke it.  By the pigeonhole principle, we can't find such a bijection if $n \neq m$, thus we've proven what we want.

Since the contrapositive is true, it follows that if $\{1, \dots, n \}$ is in bijection with $\{1, \dots, m \}$, then $n = m$.